# Как задать MainClass для манифест-файла, созданного при сборке Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Делаю сборку проекта в Intellij Idea с использованием Maven. При сборке `jar`-файла, в нем создается манифест. При запуске этого файла, получаю ошибку вида:

Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleBot

Манифест в `jar` создается такого вида:

```txt
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Dmitriy
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_45
Main-Class: SimpleBot
```

Фрагмент `pom.xml` файла с объявлением `mainClass` выглядит следующим образом:

```xml
...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>SimpleBot</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

...

Структура файлов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста подскажите, в чем заключается ошибка? Пробовал менять струкруту файлов, указывать `main.java.SimpleBot` и `java.SimpleBot` - безуспешно.
Пробовал создать `jar` через артифакт, - там все корректно получается, манифест собирается и приложение запускается. Содержимое манифеста такое же (в части MainClass).
Однако мне необходима сборка именно через мавен, для деплоя через CLI

Comment: А так `<mainClass>.SimpleBot</mainClass>`? А лучше сделайте пакет (package)

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить рефакторинг - добавить пакет, а в него переместить класс SimpleBot, скорее всего при запуске, класслоадер ожидает у классов наличие пакета, как обязательного атрибута пути к классу.

Comment: Добавил в папку java новую подпапку - к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: @Дмитрий, а после перемещения класса в пакет, в этом теге `<mainClass>SimpleBot</mainClass>` пакетный путь добавили ? Что-то вроде `<mainClass>somepackage.SimpleBot</mainClass>`

Comment: и первой строкой файла SimpleClass.java должно быть объявление накета `package somepackage;`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```java
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не модульная структура и всего 1 pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.Application</mainClass> // где Application - ваш главный класс
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Если модулей больше, оберните `<plugins>`еще в `<pluginManagement>`

Не забудьте сделать `clean`, затем собрать проект (build project, молоточек в IntelliJ IDEA), затем запустить `mvn package`.